# ELK stack pods on pending state Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I created a single host Kubernetes cluster for test purposes by using this link(with Docker 19.3.8):

https://computingforgeeks.com/install-kubernetes-cluster-on-centos-with-kubeadm/

The cluster is up and running, every system pod is active/running.

The purpose i created this cluster to test some configurations via kubernetes on an ELK stack(mainly on elasticsearch itself.)

The yaml file is like the one below:

```yaml
    #namespace define
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    metadata:
      name: testlog
    
    ---
    #esnodes
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode1
      name: testnode1
      namespace: testlog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: testnode1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: testnode1
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
            - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
              value: unlimited
            - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
              value: "true"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: cluster.name
              value: testcluster
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: http.cors.allow-origin
              value: "*"
            - name: network.host
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: node.data
              value: "false"
            - name: node.name
              value: testnode1
            image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
            name: testnode1
            securityContext:
              privileged: true
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: testnode1-claim0
    #      restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: testnode1-claim0
              hostPath:
                path: /logtest/es1
                type: DirectoryOrCreate
    
    ---
    #es1 portservice
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: testnode1-service
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: testnode1
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port: 9200
        nodePort: 9201
        targetPort: 9200
        protocol: TCP
        name: testnode1-9200
      - port: 9300
        nodePort: 9301
        targetPort: 9300
        protocol: TCP
        name: testnode1-9300
      selector:
        app: testnode1
    
    
    ---
    #es1 dns
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: testnode1
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: testnode1
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
        app: testnode1
    
    ---
    
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode2
      name: testnode2
      namespace: testlog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: testnode2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: testnode2
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
            - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
              value: unlimited
            - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
              value: "true"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: cluster.name
              value: testcluster
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: http.cors.allow-origin
              value: "*"
            - name: network.host
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: node.data
              value: "true"
            - name: node.name
              value: testnode2
            image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
            name: testnode2
            securityContext:
              privileged: true
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: testnode2-claim0
    #      restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: testnode2-claim0
              hostPath:
                path: /logtest/es2
                type: DirectoryOrCreate
    
    ---
    
    #es1 dns
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: testnode2
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: testnode2
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
        app: testnode2
    
    ---
    
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode3
      name: testnode3
      namespace: testlog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: testnode3
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: testnode3
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
            - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
              value: unlimited
            - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
              value: "true"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: cluster.name
              value: testcluster
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
            - name: http.cors.allow-origin
              value: "*"
            - name: network.host
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: node.data
              value: "true"
            - name: node.name
              value: testnode3
            image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
            name: testnode3
            securityContext:
              privileged: true
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: testnode3-claim0
    #      restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: testnode3-claim0
              hostPath:
                path: /logtest/es3
                type: DirectoryOrCreate
    
    ---
    
    #es3 dns
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: testnode3
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: testnode3
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
        app: testnode3
    
    ---
    
    #kibana dep
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
      name: kibana
      namespace: testlog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: kibana
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: kibana
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://testnode1:9200
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
              value: http://testnode1:9200
            image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.8.0
            name: kibana
    #      restartPolicy: Always
    
    ---
    #kibana  dns
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: kibana
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
        app: kibana
    ---
    #kibana port servi
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: kibana-service
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port: 5601
        nodePort: 5602
        targetPort: 5601
        protocol: TCP
        name: kibana
      selector:
        app: kibana
    
    ---
    
    #elasticsearch-hq deployment
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-hq
      name: elasticsearch-hq
      namespace: testlog
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: elasticsearch-hq
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: elasticsearch-hq
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
            name: elasticsearch-hq
    #      restartPolicy: Always
    
    ---
    #elasticsearch-hq port service
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: elasticsearch-hq-service
      namespace: testlog
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-hq
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port: 8081
        nodePort: 8081
        targetPort: 5000
        protocol: TCP
        name: elasticsearch-hq
      selector:
        app: elasticsearch-hq
```

after kubectl create command I get the following output:

```
    namespace/testlog created
    deployment.apps/testnode1 created
    service/testnode1-service created
    service/testnode1 created
    deployment.apps/testnode2 created
    service/testnode2 created
    deployment.apps/testnode3 created
    service/testnode3 created
    deployment.apps/kibana created
    service/kibana created
    service/kibana-service created
    deployment.apps/elasticsearch-hq created
    service/elasticsearch-hq-service created
```

but the pods created as a result are on pending status for the last hour. There is also no output when I enter `kubectl logs <podname> -n <namespace>` . There is also no such containers when I type `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` . I'm extremely new to Kubernetes and couldn't figure out the reason behind this.

output of `kubectl describe pod <podname> -n <namespace>` :

```
Name:           testnode1-6c9d65ddf5-jj7dj
Namespace:      testlog
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=testnode1
                pod-template-hash=6c9d65ddf5
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/testnode1-6c9d65ddf5
Containers:
  testnode1:
    Image:      amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:                  -Xms768m -Xmx768m
      MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY:             unlimited
      bootstrap.memory_lock:         true
      cluster.initial_master_nodes:  testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
      cluster.name:                  testcluster
      discovery.seed_hosts:          testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
      http.cors.allow-origin:        *
      network.host:                  0.0.0.0
      node.data:                     false
      node.name:                     testnode1
    Mounts:
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from testnode1-claim0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gzmng (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  testnode1-claim0:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /logtest/es1
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  default-token-gzmng:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gzmng
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m2s (x62 over 85m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Comment: try to see the output of `kubectl describe pod` and the events section at the end to see why they are pending.

Comment: it is good to edit the question to add the missing/requested info instead of adding an asnwer. btw, if you see the events, you see that there is just one node i.e. master and there is a taint set on the node so the pod can't get scheduled on it unless it has a matching toleration: `0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.` do you not have more nodes in the cluster: `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added the info to the original post. This is the only node i'm using for now. As i said I'm trying to get a grasp on the overall configurations and working principals first.

Comment: in that case, the other answer should work if you remove the taint from the master node but keep in mind it is not recommended for production scenarios.

Comment: What is the approach if i encounter this error in a multinode cluster?

Comment: there will some nodes without a taint and the pods will get scheduled on those nodes. further, if all nodes have some taints then the pods will get scheduled on the nodes only if has the matching toleration on them. read about the theory in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the message clearly shows what's wrong. The single node in your cluster is tainted with `{node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }`.

Run this command to remove the taint:

`kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

This is clearly mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#control-plane-node-isolation)

Read more about Taints & Tolerations [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)

Comment: No probs. Even though you edited the post with the required info, you should Delete your answer as it was only added information and wasn't supposed to be answer.